Three JS loop through materials
I want to search for the material called COIN and assign a new texture to it. I know it's material number 0, but what I want is to search through the materials and if it finds a name match, assign the texture.
object.traverse( function( node ) {
  if (node.isMesh) {
    if ( node.material[0].name == 'COIN' ) {
      node.material = textura
    } 
  }
})
// Works perfect

Looking something like:
if ( node.material[].name == 'COIN' )
// Error

How can I loop through the object's textures to find the one I'm interested in without knowing the material index?
Just in case it matters, the object format is FBX.
Thanks!!!

Found a solution on the spanish stackoverflow:
object.traverse( function( node ) {
  if (node.isMesh) {
    node.material.forEach((material, index) => {
      if (material.name === 'COIN') {
        node.material[index] = textura;
      }
    });
  }
});


You get the same results, if you know part name, but I see now what you meant more clearly…
